# Stripping a list returns blank value

Tags: python, jupyter, strip

Hey there I'm trying to strip a list from newlines, however the output I get is blank. What am I doing wrong? I'm using jupyter to run it

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_3D_Viewer'
paragraphs = []
titles = []
scraped_content = []
scraped_titles = []
scraped_list = []

response = requests.get(url, time.sleep(2)) 
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
paragraphs = soup2.find_all('p')
lists = soup2.find_all('ul')
titles = soup2.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-4]$'))
               
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    paragraphs = [paragraph.text]
    paragraphs = paragraph.get_text()
    scraped_content.append(paragraphs)
        
for title in titles:
    titles = [title.text]
    titles = title.get_text()
    scraped_titles.append(titles)
                       
scraped_content = list(map(str.strip, scraped_content))
scraped_content
```

Comment: What does the `scraped_content` look like before you execute the `map` operation on it?

Comment: can you give the sample of paragraph you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it would work except for the parameters to `requests.get`.

- Remove the second argument to `requests.get`, as it is unnecessary and possibly causing problems. If you meant to add a timeout of 2 seconds, then use `timeout=2` instead, [as documented](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).
- Make sure you are running all of the code in one cell so that none of the data is possibly getting corrupted.
- If you're behind a proxy/firewall from where you're running Jupyter server, then that can affect the results of requests.
- No need to declare variables like `paragraphs` and `titles` and then reassign them right away. You can use list comprehensions to get the results more directly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import re
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_3D_Viewer'

response = requests.get(url) 
paragraphs = []
titles = []
scraped_content = []
scraped_titles = []
scraped_list = []
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
paragraphs = soup2.find_all('p')
lists = soup2.find_all('ul')
titles = soup2.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-4]$'))

scraped_content = [paragraph.get_text() for paragraph in paragraphs]

scraped_titles = [title.get_text() for title in titles]

trimmed_content = [content.strip() for content in scraped_content]
trimmed_content
```

Output (truncated, only the first line is shown):

```
['3D Viewer (formerly Mixed Reality Viewer and before that, View 3D)[2][3][4] is a 3D object viewer and Augmented Reality application that was first included in Windows 10 1703. It supports the .fbx, .3mf, .obj, and .stl  and many more file formats[5] listed in features section.',
...
```